# Creating and calling cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have to create a cookie and then retrieve the cookie that was stored.

How do I go about doing this? The cookie that is being stored, has to have information that I typed in on my Hobbies page that is being displayed on the Summary page.

I have to save the cookies, then redirect to Summary2 and call the cookie that was stored when i hit a button. Here is the code i have so far that i believe correlates with what I am asking

```
 protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vacations = Session["Vacations"] as string;
        string hobbies = Session["Hobbies"] as string;
        string classes = Session["Classes"] as string;

        lblDisplay.Text = "Your favorite vacations spots are: " + vacations + "<br />" +
        "Your hobbies are: " + hobbies + "<br />" +
        "Your IT Classes are: " + classes;

    }
    protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cookies["Hobbies"].Value = hobbies;
        Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);

        HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("lastVisit");
        aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);

        Response.Redirect("Summary2.aspx", true);
    }
```

and here is what i have for retreiving the cookies on my Summary2 page...

```
protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["userName"] != null)
            lblDisplay.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userName"].Value);

        if (Request.Cookies["userName"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["userName"];
            lblDisplay.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
        }

    }
```

I mainly do not know how to store the information that was entered in my Hobbies page. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the "Cookie" in your Site.Master and you can access it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had the cookies method in the wrong button command and in my Summary2 i had it calling the wrong cookie name.